# System.ServiceModel: A call to SSPI falied, Target Principle Name is incorrect

Tags: wcf, x509certificate, userprincipal, upn

I am attempting to hit a WCF service endpoint.  However, I keep getting the above exception on the server (when I check the logs) whenever I attempt to hit the service.
The service basically has mutual certificate behaviour.  It lists a Client certificate and a Service Certificate.  Also, It specifies a userPrincipleName under the endpoint\identity section of its web.conf... An example of the config file of a similar set up is shown below...

```
        <endpoint address="<nicelyAddressEndpoint>"
            binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="customTcpBinding"
            contract="<service>" name="<smartSoundingCamelCasedServiceName>">
            <identity>
                <userPrincipalName value="<example>@yourMother.net" />
            </identity>
        </endpoint>
```

would be the endpoint that I described.

```
  <service name="<NiceServiceName>" behaviorConfiguration="MutualCertificateBehavior">
    <endpoint address="" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="CustomMCBinding" contract="IServiceContractThatIsntWrittenPoorley"/>
  </service>

    <behavior name="MutualCertificateBehavior">
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceCredentials>
        <clientCertificate>
          <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerOrChainTrust" revocationMode="NoCheck" includeWindowsGroups="false"/>
          <certificate findValue="<CertName>" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="Root" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
        </clientCertificate>
        <serviceCertificate findValue="<ServiceCert>" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="Root" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
      </serviceCredentials>
    </behavior>
```

And that would be the service and the behavior.

I am doing what I can to attempt to get data out of this thing.  I am running into one sticking point, and I am not sure if it is because I am going about this the wrong way, or that I am close and I just need to get over a minor hurtle.  In my client web.config I set up the endpoint behavior similarly...

```
      <behavior name="ClientCertificateBehvior">
        <clientCredentials>              
          <clientCertificate findValue="<XXX>"
                             storeLocation="LocalMachine"
                             storeName="My"
                             x509FindType="FindBySubjectName"/>
          <serviceCertificate>
            <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerOrChainTrust" revocationMode="NoCheck" />
            <defaultCertificate findValue="<XXX>" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="Root" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
          </serviceCertificate>
        </clientCredentials>
      </behavior>
```

And this is my endpoint...

```
        <endpoint address="xxx.xxx.xxx"
            behaviorConfiguration="ClientCertificateBehvior" binding="customBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="CustomBinding_IVPOService" contract="VPOServiceEndPoint.IVPOService"
            name="CustomBinding_IVPOService">
            <identity>
                <dns value="xxx" />
                <userPrincipalName value="yyy@xxx.net" />
            </identity>
        </endpoint>
```

Now I am getting this exception whenever I attempt to hit this service...

```
The identity check failed for the outgoing message. The expected identity is 'identity(http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/right/possessproperty: http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/upn)' for the 'xxxxxx' target endpoint.
```

I will note that I have the certificate in the appropriate store listed on my local machine and I have granted the appropriate writes to that certificate.  I am to the point where I realize that I am making more trouble for myself here, and I am attempting to figure out what is the right thing to do instead of throwing things against the wall and seeing what sticks.  What step am I missing?  What is the best way to receive data from a MutualCertificate secured service?  How can I best get the right userPrinciplename?  I thought it would be what is listed in the servie web.config?  Am I going about this in the right way?  Am I getting close or just making a bigger mess for myself?